# Как остановить цикл в python

Tags: python

Есть следующий код:

```python
for items in slovar.get("r1").keys():
    if inp.__contains__("r1"):
        par = input(f"Введите имя параметра: {slovar.get('r1').keys()} ")
        if items in par:
            print(slovar["r1"][items])
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как пользователь ввёл значение в переменную `par`, цикл останавливался и выводил `slovar["r1"][items]`.
Как мне сделать это?

Comment: поставить break после print

Comment: не работает, я уже пробовал

Comment: Значит items не находится в par. Модет просто items == par

Comment: также не работает

Comment: Я же Вам написал "items не находится (не равно) в par". Выведите перед сравнением значения items и par и посмотрите. Не забываем, что инпут вернёт только СТРОКУ